# How to call to LinkedList with generic type

Tags: java, android

I'm using several `LinkedList` each one from different type, for example :

```
 LinkedList<A> typeA = new LinkedList<>();
 LinkedList<B> typeB = new LinkedList<>();
 LinkedList<C> typeC = new LinkedList<>();
```

and then i want to print them according to the type, so for each type I call to the appropriate function.

```
void funcA(LinkedList<A> ls)
void funcB(LinkedList<B> ls)
void funcC(LinkedList<C> ls)
```

and I wonder if the is any option of calling one function and inside that function to check the type.
Thank for those who help! Have a nice day :)

Comment: You could write a generic function, but if that is suitable depends on what your functions are going to do.

Comment: Can you be more specific of what you want achieve in `funcA()` etc? You can probably move the functionality to `A`, `B` and `C` and have cleaner code :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use a unbound generic type in the list parameter of the method, it would look as follow:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String>  listStr = Arrays.asList("A","B","C");
    List<Integer> listInt = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
    printList(listStr);
    printList(listInt);

}

private static void printList(List<?> list) {
    for(Object obj : list){
        if(obj instanceof String){
            String str = (String) obj;
            System.out.printf("String: %s \n", str);
        } else if(obj instanceof Integer){
            Integer integer = (Integer) obj;
            System.out.printf("Integer: %s \n", integer);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer :)

Answer (score 1):

As other have mentioned, you can use a generic function like:

```
public static <T> void genericFunc(LinkedList<T> ls) { 
//you can do something with the list but 
//you do not know what T is so you can't invoke T's methods 
//(apart from those belonging to Object)
}
```

If you want to have additional control over the types contained in T, assuming that all your objects inherit from a base class A, then you can do:

```
public static <T extends A> void genericFunc(LinkedList<T> ls) { 
   for (T t : ls){
       t.somePublicMethodOfA(); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use *another generic parameter* to the function to indicate how the list is to be printed based on the type.

See http://www.functionaljava.org/javadoc/4.7/functionaljava/fj/Show.html

Example:

```
void func<A>(LinkedList<A> list, Show<A> aShow) {
  listShow(aShow).printLn(list)
}
```

If you were using Scala you would make `Show[A]` an implicit parameter.

Answer (score -1):

you can use a generic method.

```
public <T> void func(LinkedList<T> ls) { // T can be any type
   // do something
}
```

Comment: Thank for the answer :)